# Is "I'll be waiting for your call" polite in a professional setting?

Tags: politeness

Someone says: "I'll call you later." What is a polite way to say "I'll be by my phone when you call, so that I won't miss it." Some people suggests that "I'll be waiting for your call" sounds a bit urgent. Is is true? If so, then what is a polite way?

Comment: This is highly context-specific. In most professional contexts it would not be impolite, but it might seem strange. In a busy professional environment you are generally not waiting for a single colleague’s/client’s call and suspending other work as you do so. Can you really guarantee that you’ll be available to take their call? That said, I can imagine extreme contexts where you would want to express this sort of implied guarantee (confirmation of job offer, biggest sale of the year, you’re talking to the CEO of your company, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound impolite. I see no problem with it.

"I'll call you back" is sometimes (not always) used to say "I'm not that interested in you", so replying with "I'll be waiting" is a fair way to say "I hope that you will actually do that and not just forget about me". You might want to express some urgency.

On the other hand you could just reply "Okay", "Thank-you", "till then" or "talk to you later". There is no fixed reply.